# Django static files versions

Tags: python, django, static

How do you control  version of your static files in Django? I [wrote custom templatetag](https://bitbucket.org/ad3w/django-sstatic/overview) which adds the modification date as GET parameter of file URL, but would like to know - whether I'm doing.

Tag code:

```
import os

from django import template
from django.conf import settings


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def sstatic(path):
    '''
    Returns absolute URL to static file with versioning.
    '''
    full_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, path)
    try:
        # Get file modification time.
        mtime = os.path.getmtime(full_path)
        return '%s%s?%s' % (settings.STATIC_URL, path, mtime)
    except OSError:
        # Returns normal url if this file was not found in filesystem.
        return '%s%s' % (settings.STATIC_URL, path)
```

Comment: This will return a path, but how do you modify the actual filenames so they correspond to that path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Applications such as [django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor), and [django-pipeline](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline) are good for these sort of things.

Comment: +1 for django-pipeline. Works great and is easy to install. I use YUI Compressor with it. Combines, minifies and versions your css/js. In debug mode, it serves the uncombined/minified files for easier debugging.

Comment: I use django-compressor and haven't had any problems with it. I'm not sure about django-pipeline, but django-compressor also allows preprocessing things like LESS, SASS, CoffeScript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.7 added [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage) which is designed to do this as part of the `collectstatic` cycle by appending hashes to filenames. By default it applies to all filetypes.

If you want to use it but want to specify which filetypes are versioned, then I wrote [an extension](https://github.com/TomAnthony/django-flexible-manifest-staticfiles) that allows you to include / exclude files by path pattern.

As of Django 2.2 this ManifestStaticFilesStorage is still the recommended way to do this.